# How to specify consecutive returns in gmock?

Tags: c++, mockito, googletest, googlemock

In Mockito we can specify multiple returns like (taken from [here](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html)):

```
//you can set different behavior for consecutive method calls.
 //Last stubbing (e.g: thenReturn("foo")) determines the behavior of further consecutive calls.
 when(mock.someMethod("some arg"))
  .thenReturn(new RuntimeException())
  .thenReturn("foo");

 //There is a shorter way of consecutive stubbing:
 when(mock.someMethod()).thenReturn(1,2,3);
 when(mock.otherMethod()).thenThrow(exc1, exc2);
```

Is there a way to specify multiple returns for a mock made with gmock? Currently I have:

```
store_mock_ = std::make_shared<StorageMock>();
ON_CALL(*store_mock_, getFileName(_)).Return("file1").Return("file2");
```

which doesn't compile because I can't figure out multiple returns in gmock. Is this possible with gmock? If not, is there another way to solve this problem? I've found that we can `EXPECT` multiple return values like:

```
using ::testing::Return;...
EXPECT_CALL(turtle, GetX())
    .WillOnce(Return(100))
    .WillOnce(Return(200))
    .WillOnce(Return(300));
```

However, I haven't found any docs for mocking multiple returns with `ON_CALL`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`ON_CALL` is more used for setting default behavior of the function. I.e. you know that in tested code the mocked function is called, you want to set some default value, but it is not actually important how many times function is called.

The [example](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Setting_the_Default_Actions_for_a_Mock_Method):

```
  ON_CALL(foo, Sign(_))
      .WillByDefault(Return(-1));
  ON_CALL(foo, Sign(0))
      .WillByDefault(Return(0));
  ON_CALL(foo, Sign(Gt(0)))
      .WillByDefault(Return(1));
```

To get your desired behavior I'd use [expectations](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Setting_Expectations) - you already provided some example in question, just to show more - an example when you expect `1`, `2` then always `3`:

```
  EXPECT_CALL(foo, Sign(_))
      .WillOnce(Return(1))
      .WillOnce(Return(2))
      .WillRepeatedly(Return(3));
```

`EXPECT_CALL` "way" might be troublesome when you want to set this in test fixture `SetUp` - and some tests might call `foo` only once. But, of course, there are ways to "control" `ON_CALL` return value for subsequent calls - but you must do it with special actions - like getting result of some function - like in this example:

```
class IDummy
{
public:
    virtual int foo() = 0;
};

class DummyMock : public IDummy
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(foo, int());
};
using namespace ::testing;
class DummyTestSuite : public Test
{
protected:
    DummyMock dummy;
    void SetUp() override
    {
        ON_CALL(dummy, foo())
           .WillByDefault(
                 InvokeWithoutArgs(this, &DummyTestSuite::IncrementDummy));
    }
    int dummyValue = 0;
    int IncrementDummy()
    {
        return ++dummyValue;
    }

};


TEST_F(DummyTestSuite, aaa)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(1, dummy.foo());
    ASSERT_EQ(2, dummy.foo());
    ASSERT_EQ(3, dummy.foo());

}
```

Comment: My understanding of expectations is that they are what we expect to be returned, not what should actually be returned by the mock. Is that incorrect? Your `IncrementDummy` example is really helpful. Kinda sucks that the best way to define multiple returns is so involved. :(

Comment: If I understand you correctly - then yes. My example is very artificial - we never test by assertion what mocks returns - I just write this test to show that this mechanism works.  More general we can say that `EXPECT_CALL`is for cases when we expects that mocked function  is called from within tested code. It is not necessary to set "return value" - e.g. it is quite often that we expect void function to be called....

Comment: Hi, I tried to use this chain of WillOnces with InvokeArgument but it does not compile. In my case I have a callback which accepts error codes and I would like to invoke this callback with different error codes. 

`EXPECT_CALL(*mockedObj, Start(_, _, _)).WillOnce(InvokeArgument<2>(Error::Success)).WillOnce(InvokeArgument<2>(Error::InternalError));`

Am I missing something or this kind of chaining will not work with InvokeArgument?

Comment: @MherDidaryan  on which position in `Start` argument list do you have this callback? Maybe you made simple mistake with this index 2?  The other possibility is that `Start` has different return value than your callback. Anyway - you probably have to ask question with this problem, attaching compiler output

Comment: @MherDidaryan you have to ask separate question describing the problem with simplified code that shows the problem with compiler version and output. There is no way to help you otherwise.

Comment: @PiotrNycz yes you are right this was a dumb mistake. Everything works as expected.

Answer (score 18):

@PiotrNycz's answer is correct and the preferred solution.

An alternative approach via a lambda function *may* give you more flexibility:

```
uint32_t callCount = 0;
ON_CALL(*turtle, GetX())
    .WillByDefault(testing::Invoke(
        [&callCount]() -> int {
            return ++callCount * 100;
        }
    ));
```

Comment: This is what **I** want - thanks!